# Passing fixed-size Eigen matrices as arguments to function calling for dynamic-size matrices

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, typedef, eigen

I am writing a small linear algebra utility library on top of Eigen for my personal code-base. To try to make it as flexible as possible, I typedefed different Eigen matrix types for use as parameters. However, an issue I keep running into is that when I use it, I can't pass a fixed-size (i.e. set at compile-time) matrix as the argument to a function that has a dynamically-sized (set at runtime) matrix typedef as a parameter. I could understand the inverse--not being able to pass a dynamic-sized matrix as fixed due to compile-time checks, but it seems this ought to work.

A test-able example is the `pdist2` function below (which really ought to have a native implementation in the Eigen API).

```
#include <Eigen/Core>

namespace Eigen
{
    template <typename T>
    using MatrixXT = Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>;
}

// X is M x N
// Y is M x K
// Output is N x K
template <typename T>
inline Eigen::MatrixXT<T> pdist2(const Eigen::MatrixXT<T> &X, const Eigen::MatrixXT<T> &Y)
{
    // ASSERT(X.rows() == Y.rows(), "Input observations must have same number of rows (" + 
    //  std::to_string(X.rows()) + "!=" + std::to_string(Y.rows()) + ")");

    Eigen::MatrixXT<T> dists = X.colwise().squaredNorm().transpose() * Eigen::MatrixXT<T>::Ones(1, Y.cols()) +
        Eigen::MatrixXT<T>::Ones(X.cols(), 1) * Y.colwise().squaredNorm() -
        2 * X.transpose() * Y;

    return dists;
}
```

This code does not compile:

```
Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 5> X;
X << 8.147236863931790, 9.133758561390193, 2.784982188670484, 9.648885351992766, 9.571669482429456,
     9.057919370756192, 6.323592462254095, 5.468815192049838, 1.576130816775483, 4.853756487228412,
     1.269868162935061, 0.975404049994095, 9.575068354342976, 9.705927817606156, 8.002804688888002;

Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 4> Y;
Y << 1.418863386272153, 7.922073295595544, 0.357116785741896, 6.787351548577734,
     4.217612826262750, 9.594924263929030, 8.491293058687772, 7.577401305783335,
     9.157355251890671, 6.557406991565868, 9.339932477575505, 7.431324681249162;

Eigen::Matrix<double, 5, 4> D = pdist2(X, Y);
```

The above function has been unit tested and evaluates correctly, but it will only work if `X` and `Y` are `Eigen::MatrixXd` types. It seems it must be my template typedef causing the issue, but it's just a dynamically (i.e. at runtime) sized matrix with a templated type.

The error reads:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘pdist2(Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 5>&, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 4>&)’
  Eigen::Matrix<double, 5, 4> D = Util::Math::pdist2(X, Y);
                                                              ^
note: candidate: template<class T> Eigen::MatrixXT<T> Util::Math::pdist2(Eigen::MatrixXT<T>&, Eigen::MatrixXT<T>&)
   inline Eigen::MatrixXT<T> pdist2(const Eigen::MatrixXT<T> &X, const Eigen::MatrixXT<T> &Y)
                         ^
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   template argument ‘3’ does not match ‘#‘integer_cst’ not supported by dump_decl#<declaration error>’
  Eigen::Matrix<double, 5, 4> D_est = Util::Math::pdist2(X, Y);
                                                              ^
note:   ‘Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 5>’ is not derived from ‘Eigen::MatrixXT<T>’
```

**Why is this not working?** Or perhaps more specifically, **how do I use a templated typedef** to ensure that my fixed-size matrices *do* derive from `Eigen::MatrixXT<T>`?

Note: This is all using Eigen 3.3.3.

Comment: That is not possible.  `Matrix<double, 5, 4>` and `MatrixXt<double>` are different types.  That means you cannot bind a reference to `MatrixXt<double>` to an instance of `Matrix<double, 5, 4>`.  Use pass by value, or take a look at `Eigen::Ref`.

Comment: @HenriMenke I don't think that's the problem, there are conversions going on (even if the dims are incorrect, you'd get an assert error). The issue is with deducing the template type `T`, still trying to figuring out why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `Matrix<double, 3, 5>` and `MatrixXT<double>` are not the same type, therefore, the only way to pass the former to `pdist2` is to convert it to a `MatrixXT<double>`. This would be done automatically by the compiler if `pdist2` were not a template function:

```
MatrixXT<double> pdist2(const MatrixXT<double>&,const MatrixXT<double>&);
```

but since pdist2 is templated **and** that `MatrixXT<double>` is not a base class of `Matrix<double, 3, 5>`, in C++ the compiler is not allowed to automatically deduced the template parameter to instantiate pdist2. The solution for you is to generalize even more your function to take any `MatrixBase<>` as inputs:

```
template<typename D1,typename D2>
Matrix<typename D1::Scalar,D1::ColsAtCompileTime,D2::ColsAtCompileTime>
pdist2(const MatrixBase<D1>& _X,const MatrixBase<D2>& _Y);
```

Since X and Y are going to be used multiple times, and that they can now be arbitrary expressions (including a costly matrix product), you might want to let Eigen evaluate the arguments if needed, to this end, you can use `Ref`:

```
Ref<const typename D1::PlainObject> X(_X);
Ref<const typename D2::PlainObject> Y(_Y);
```

This way X will be evaluated if it cannot be represented as a pointer+stride to actual values.

Comment: Could you articulate why calling the function as `pdist2<double>(X, Y)` circumvents the template parameter deduction problem?

Comment: In this case the compiler does not have to deduce the any template parameter for you, `pdist2<double>` thus behaves exactly like the non-templated function of my answer, and implicit conversion from different Matrix types applies.

Comment: @ggael You should start a Kickstarter to write an authoritative Eigen book. I would pay a lot for that.